# Python Pandas, transform dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe (sim_2005):

```
Date         ELEM1 ELEM2 ... ELEM1133
2005-01-01   0.021 2.455 ... 345.2
2005-01-02   0.321 2.331 ... 355.1
...          ...   ...   ... ...
2005-12-31   0.789 3.456 ... 459.9
[365 rows x 1133 columns]
```

I need to import this into a (postgresql) Database with the following format:

```
ID     Date        ELEM     Value
1      2005-01-01  ELEM1    0.021
2      2005-01-02  ELEM1    0.321
...
366    2005-01-01  ELEM2    2.455
367    2005-01-02  ELEM2    2.331
...
402983 2005-01-01  ELEM1133 345.2
402984 2005-01-02  ELEM1133 355.1
...
403348 2005-12-31  ELEM1133 459.9
```

I'm trying my best with iterating over the columns and concatenating it step by step,

```
for column in sim_2005:
    sim_concat = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(sim_2005.columns.values), sim_2005.ix[:, column]], ignore_index=True)
```

which produces by far not what I'm looking for.

I also tried pandas pivot function, groupby, etc... but I guess my understanding of pandas and python in general is not sufficient for this transformation. Any help?

**Edit:**

Thanks, pd.melt was the answer!

```
 sim_2005_melted = pd.melt(sim_2005, id_vars=sim_2005.index.name, value_vars=list(sim_2005.columns.values), var_name='ELEM', value_name='Q_sim').sort(columns='Date')
```

Results in:

```
ID     Date   ELEM     Q_sim
1      NaN    ELEM1    0.021
2      NaN    ELEM1    0.321
...
366    NaN    ELEM2    2.455
367    NaN    ELEM2    2.331
...
402983 NaN    ELEM1133 345.2
402984 NaN    ELEM1133 355.1
```

For some reason the datetime index is not transported over, but the overall structure is exactly how I wanted it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing a "wide-to-narrow" transformation, in `pandas` terminology. One way to do this is with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html).

In this case, you could do something like:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['ELEM1', 'ELEM2']).sort(columns='Date')
```

for a dataframe with two "wide" columns `['ELEM1', 'ELEM2']`. For your ~1K columns in the example, you'd obviously not write them by hand, and rather create `value_vars` using some sort of list comprehension.

---

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': range(4),
    'ELEM1': range(1, 5),
    'ELEM2': range(11, 15),
    'ELEM2': range(-5, -1)
})

>> df
    Date    ELEM1   ELEM2
0   0   1   -5
1   1   2   -4
2   2   3   -3
3   3   4   -2

>> pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['ELEM1', 'ELEM2']).sort(columns='Date')
    Date    variable    value
0   0   ELEM1   1
4   0   ELEM2   -5
1   1   ELEM1   2
5   1   ELEM2   -4
2   2   ELEM1   3
6   2   ELEM2   -3
3   3   ELEM1   4
7   3   ELEM2   -2
```

Comment: Thanks @ami-tavory ! That was exactly what I was looking for, but for some reason the datetime identifier is all NaN values in the new df?!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you like, I could change my example to datetimes, and perhaps you could see from there where it differs from your problem.

Comment: That would be awesome! I edited my OP, to clarify my problem.

Comment: I posted that datetime problem [as a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984167/python-pandas-pd-melt-a-dataframe-with-datetime-index-results-in-nan) since you basically answered this question here! Thanks again!